# RVIZ2 not displaying visuals

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started learning ROS2 by [porting the osrf prius simulation to ROS2](https://github.com/NovoG93/car_demo/tree/ros2) and here i ran into the problem that rviz2 is not displaying the visuals (as seen in the figure)
[image: image description]

However when I change the `Description Source` to File the visuales are displayed (see below)
[image: image description]

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit:
I am loading the urdf as follows:

```
       urdf = os.path.join(
           get_package_share_directory("prius_description"),
           "urdf", urdf_file_name)
       
       Node(
           package="robot_state_publisher",
           executable="robot_state_publisher",
           name="robot_state_publisher",
           namespace="prius",
           output="screen",
           parameters=[{"use_sim_time": use_sim_time, "robot_description": robot_desc}],
           arguments=[urdf]
        ),
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402294/rviz2-not-displaying-visuals/) by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2022-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just after editing my question I realized I am using a namespace on the robot_state_publisher. Thus I needed to change the `Description Topic` in rviz2 to `/prius/robot_description` to make it work

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2022-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MASAAB](https://answers.ros.org/users/120569/masaab/) on 2023-03-04**:
can you please elaborate on this, as I'm facing the same problem

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2023-03-05**:
In the case above I needed to change the topic on which to listen for the urdf file.
However, on my current simulation I am facing the problem again and I don't know how to fix it.
If you you find something please inform me, I will do so as well.